# I want to integrate paytm payment gateway in php

Tags: php, paytm

I want to generate a checksum and match the Paytm payment utility checksum using PHP

for more read this documentation **installing the Paytm Checksum utility with the composer**

https://business.paytm.com/docs/checksum/

I have installed the Paytm Checksum utility  using the command in php

```
composer require paytm/paytmchecksum
```

I'm including a PHP class with

`require_once("./vendor/Paytm/paytmchecksum/paytmchecksum/paytmchecksum.php");`

but when the code is executed I receive this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PaytmChecksum" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\checksum\checksum_gen.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\checksum\checksum_gen.php on line 18
```

I still can't figure out what's the problem. I'm 99% sure it's incorrect.

No solution has been found yet

checksum_gen.php

```
$paytmChecksum = PaytmChecksum::generateSignature($body, 'YOUR_MERCHANT_KEY');
echo sprintf("generateSignature Returns: %s\n", $paytmChecksum);
```

Comment: If you are using `composer`, why do you need `require_once` explicitly to include the file?

Comment: Use it as `\paytm\paytmchecksum\PaytmChecksum::generateSignature` . See the namespace [here](https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_PHP_Checksum/blob/master/paytmchecksum/PaytmChecksum.php)